# ‘unordered_set’ does not name a type when declaring it inside a header file

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

Hi I have a code which has structure explained below. This is not the actual code but I've tried to simulate the problem and it gives same error.

I've a file called classTest.cpp which contains:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    test f;
    f.insert(10);
    cout<<f.search(10)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

header.h contains following code:

```
#include<unordered_set>
class test
{
    public:
    int apple;
    unordered_set<int> set;
    bool search(int a);
    void insert(int a);
};
bool test::search(int a)
{
    if(apple!=a)
        return false;
    return true;
        /*
    if(set.find(a) == set.end())
        return false;
    return true;*/
}


void test::insert(int a)
{
    apple = a;
    //set.insert(a);
}
```

When i compile classTest.cpp I get following error:

```
header.h:6:2: error: ‘unordered_set’ does not name a type
  unordered_set<int> set;
```

But when I copy the header.h content and paste it into classTest.cpp it works fine. I am unable to understand the reason. Is there some basic concept that I'm missing?

Comment: You're including it *before* the `using namespace std;`, but (apparently) when you pasted it in, you put it after that. Change it to `std::unordered_set` in the header, and see if things don't work a bit better.

Comment: Use `std::unordered_set` instead. An since you seem to not know what `using namespace std;` does: Just stop using it and qualify the names with `std::` instead.

Comment: Oh! It was such stupid mistake. Working now.

Comment: That's not stupid. Sitting down with shuriken in your pocket... That's stupid.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments: you are attempting to use `unordered_set` without qualifying the namespace it comes from. Your compiler thus doesn't know what type it is.

This works when you copy your declaration of `test` into *classTest.cpp* because that file has a `using namespace std`.

You should [always qualify your types with their namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) (if for no other reason than to avoid problems like this). In this case, to solve your problem, you should write:

```
std::unordered_set<int> set;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a silly mistake. I assumed that there is no need for std:: as I specified namespace but missed the ordering. But yes it is solved now. I moved importing the header after using namespace std.